# Tremaux Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, pathfinding

I am trying to implement Tremaux Algorithm for a 2D maze. So far the robot works well however I have some problems with `retraceStep()`. I'm not asking how to implement that, but I just want to make sure that there are no serious logical flaws with my code.

```
 @Override
    public boolean drive2Exit() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Direction> availableDirections = new ArrayList<Direction>(); //dont' forget to clear!!!
        while (!robot.isAtGoal() && robot.getBatteryLevel() >= robot.getEnergyForStepForward()) {
            addPositionToVisited();
            if (validJunction()) { //Visited cells are treated as walls. Junctions return true if there is no wall to the left or right
                availableDirections = getAvailableDirections();
                int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(availableDirections.size());
                Direction direction = availableDirections.get(index);
                turnRobot(direction);
                try {
                    robot.move(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                availableDirections.clear();
            } else if (canMoveForward()) { //Visited cells are treated as walls
                try {
                    robot.move(1);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            } else {
                while (!validJunction()) {
                    retraceStep();
                }
            }
        }
        if (robot.isAtGoal())
            return true;
        else if (robot.getBatteryLevel() < robot.getEnergyForStepForward()) 
            throw new Exception();
        return false;
    }
```

The `retraceStep()` is simply a left hand wallfollower algorithm:

```
protected void retraceStep() throws Exception {
    if (robot.distanceToObstacle(Direction.LEFT) != 0) {
        robot.rotate(Turn.LEFT);
        try {
            robot.move(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    } else if (robot.distanceToObstacle(Direction.FORWARD) != 0) {
        try {
            robot.move(1);
        } catch (Exception e){}
    } else if (robot.isAtJunction()) {
        robot.rotate(Turn.RIGHT);
        try {
            robot.move(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    } else {
        robot.rotate(Turn.AROUND);
        try {
            robot.move(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Any tips on restructuring or anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`throws Exception` is rarely a good idea.  Consider reusing existing exceptions (IllegalStateException?) or defining exceptions specific to your domain (NoPathToTargetException?).  Otherwise, callers of your methods will be forced to handle the top-level `Exception` throwable type, which invariably leads to the next paragraph...

An empty `try-catch` usually causes more problems than it solves, especially when catching the `Exception` base type.  If this is a debugging construct, consider printing the stack trace to the error stream.  You'd be surprised how many *can't-happens* logging catches. ;)

Use braces even for single-statement blocks.  One day, you'll be sorry you didn't; I know I was.  I can see exceptions being made for condensed one-liners, but if you put the following statement on a new line anyway, there's no reason not to add the braces.

`availableDirections` is only used immediately following assignment, so you can pull its declaration down to the block where you need it.  You may want to factor it out and make a `getRandomAvailableDirection()` method.  (Your comment stresses that calling `clear()` is important, but I don't see why.)

Since you check for low power in your loop anyway, you may want to throw the exception (BatteryLowException?) there and then.  Another option is to make a specific return type:

```
enum DriveToExitResult {
    REACHED,
    UNREACHABLE,
    LOW_BATTERY;
}

public DriveToExitResult driveToExit() {
    // ...
```

Each branch in `retraceStep()` ultimately leads to `robot.move(1)`; we can pull that out as well, and put it at the end.

### Grand total

```
@Override
public boolean drive2Exit() {
    while (!robot.isAtGoal()) {
        if (robot.getBatteryLevel() < robot.getEnergyForStepForward()) {
            throw new BatteryLowException("Battery level too low to step forward");
        }
        addPositionToVisited();
        if (validJunction()) { //Visited cells are treated as walls. Junctions return true if there is no wall to the left or right
            Direction direction = getRandomAvailableDirection();
            assert direction != null : "valid junction but random direction was null"
            turnRobot(direction);
            robot.move(1);
        } else if (canMoveForward()) { //Visited cells are treated as walls
            robot.move(1);
        } else {
            while (!validJunction()) {
                retraceStep();
            }
        }
    }
    
    // return robot.isAtGoal();
    return true; // loop only breaks through success or exception
}

protected Direction getRandomAvailableDirection() {
    final List<Direction> availableDirections = getAvailableDirections();
    if ( availableDirections.isEmpty() ) {
        return null; // or throw an exception
    }
    final int idx = randomGenerator.nextInt(availableDirections.size());
    return availableDirections.get(idx);
}

 protected void retraceStep() {
    if (robot.distanceToObstacle(Direction.LEFT) != 0) {
        robot.rotate(Turn.LEFT);
    } else if (robot.isAtJunction()) {
        robot.rotate(Turn.RIGHT);
    } else if (robot.distanceToObstacle(Direction.FORWARD) == 0) {
        robot.rotate(Turn.AROUND);
    }   
    robot.move(1);
}
```

---

If I had to guess from the code, it feels like your issue would be here, as you said:

```
while (!validJunction()) {
    retraceStep();
}
```

The other code in your method takes care to take only a single step and check power levels each time.  This part, however, does not seem to do so.  There's a different level of abstraction here, and that's a good place to start looking for implicit assumptions and/or incompatibilities.

Log those exceptions.  You never know what is hidden there!

Comment: "You'd be surprised how many can't-happens logging catches. ;)" so true!

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shared enough to give better advice on the "big picture", but this code looks *very strange*.

---

This is a bad sign:

> ```
> try {
>     robot.move(1);
> } catch (Exception e) {
> }
> ```

First of all, you should not catch general `Exception` instances, but the most specific possible instances.

Secondly, exception handling is for handling anomalies, things that should not happen under normal circumstances. Judging by the many occurrences of this in the posted code, it looks like you're using it too casually, for things that are not really anomalies but part of the normal behavior of your algorithm. You should use conditionals instead.

---

> ```
> ArrayList<Direction> availableDirections = new ArrayList<Direction>(); //dont' forget to clear!!!
> ```

Many problems here:

- Declare variables with interface types instead of implementations. In this case `List<Direction>` instead of `ArrayList<Direction>`
- Comments are hard to see appended at the right. Put comments on the line right before the line. Do this for all comments in your code, not only here.
- The *"don't forget to clear"* comment suggests a confusion. Why not forget to clear? Be careful with semantic rules like this that the compiler cannot enforce. If something needs to be cleared, try to refactor in a way that it will be guaranteed to be cleared. In this particular case, it seems this list is only used in the `if (validJunction()) { ... }` block and cleared at the end. In fact, you could declare it inside that block, and not worry about clearing it, like this:

  ```
  if (validJunction()) { 
      List<Direction> availableDirections = getAvailableDirections();
      int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(availableDirections.size());
      Direction direction = availableDirections.get(index);
      turnRobot(direction);
      try {
          robot.move(1);
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
  } else if (canMoveForward()) {
  ```

---

I would rename some of your methods and variables, for example:

- `isValidJunction` from `validJunction`
- `random` from `randomGenerator`